Double-clicking on the backup gives an error
After the Windows 11 24H2 update I got several problems that I have not been able to resolve.
Rolling back to the previous version is not possible anymore. I have several system backups on an external disk but when I double-click on the backup icon, I get an error message saying something like
"Unexpected error - there is a problem with the catalog of the security copies. Start the session as an administrator and try to restore the files (0x810000EC)" (in Spanish)
As I am the admin of the account, so I think there is nothing else I can do. I looked at the content of the backup container, and there are several backup sets, each containing several backup folders named "Backup Files" with the date. Inside each, there is a folder with zip backup files and a folder "Catalogs". I wonder if there is a way to use these files directly, or what else I can do to restore the system from one of these backups.
I have been told that this is the backup system that came from Windows 7 but it also worked in Windows 10. Now in Windows 11, there is no reference anymore to the "Windows 7 backup system" in the recovery options. So I don't see how to restore the system from these files except with the double click on the container, which does not work. Is there 3rd party software that can do it?

For future reference: MS Windows "System Backup" only copies some of the essential files. Make a full drive image using third-party tools to assure making a complete copy of everything needed for repair.

Which "backup icon" are you trying to run? Have you opened Windows Backup and attempted to find and open the Backups through that?

"Now in Windows 11, there is no reference anymore to the Windows 7 backup system" - Open Control Panel it's under System and Security.  It's there on a 23H2 system and I have no doubt it would be there on a 24H2 system.

@music2myear The icon is visible in MS file explorer when I navigate to the folder with the backup. It appears instead of the usual folder icon. A double-click is supposed to open the restoration of the backup, but it gives an error message saying that there is a problem with  a catalog. Apparently, the backup is corrupted.
I have given up on trying to repair it and will do a clean install instead.

Ok, so have you tried opening the Backup utility and then navigating to the backup you wish to restore? The issue could be a bad file association, rather than a bad file, and this would be a simple way to check that.

@music2myear Yes. After double-clicking failed, I opened the folder and its subfolders, which are a ton of zip files and related catalogs. But this is useless if the system cannot use these data. I have not found anything about how to open the backup other than through the system's own mechanisms, which do not work. I have decided to let it go and make a clean install. I will make a backup of the defect system before on the disk with the old backup, which will, of course, erase the old one. But at this point, it's useless anyway.
